# Using Docker to create an offline version off a Django app

Tags: django, docker, offline, data-synchronization

I'm a complete newbie to Docker and before pushing into further investigations, I wanted to assert that it is the proper tool for my needs.

Here's the situation:
I have to develop a Django app that will mostly be used online. But some users will sometimes need an offline use of this app. Then, back online, they will need to push there work to the main app.

Can Docker help me to give these users a fully working offline version of the online app with very little work (from them, not me obviously...)?

Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Docker will help you with running the stack offline, so helping with all the environment parts, running the DB, App, Proxy in exactly the same way, as they are online - no matter which OS the actual user does use.

This reduces your effort to have the app running exact the same way online as offline, be it on windows, mac and linux.

Docker though will not in any way help you manage database-merges, file-system merges or anything like that. If 2 users change the same things offline and then try to sync it, you are in trouble, no matter if you use docker or you do not.

For those db merges and file merges you need different technologies, which can be used with docker - and without.

Comment: +1 for mentioning DB merges. As you state this is problem independent of using Docker. In fairness Django has schema management built-in, but there is certainly no magic bullet for merging data within the DB. One needs to build this into the automation used to create standalone copies of the app.

Comment: I wouldn't say database sync is not a problem, but it is one I can handle. My main question was on the offline part and your answer confirmed the feeling I had about how helpful Docker could be. I am in early conception steps of the project so I think I won't deal with Docker before some time but it lets me foresee the work ahead.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is, yes, Docker will help.

The longer answer is highly subjective and opinions will vary on how to achieve your desired outcome. For example it has been feasible to create off-line development copies for some time now using virtualization tools like [Virtualbox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) and [Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/).

So I would ask myself the following questions first:

1. Where do I normally deploy my application in production?
2. Is this deployment automated and repeatable?
3. Are all my application's platform (and data) dependencies captured?

A good answer for all questions puts you a great place for adopting a new technology like Docker. You just need to understand the delta between what you're doing now and what you need to be doing. Unfortunately.... it's not uncommon for companies to have what I call a "magic build server", created by a passing wizard, responsible for all software releases :-(

Assuming the worst my advice is to start with the repeatable deployment of your application using virtual machines. Use one of the CAPS tools (Chef, Ansible, Puppet, Salt) to capture all the steps required to setup your server, in other words start practising DevOps by capturing your [infrastructure as code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infrastructure_as_Code). I highly recommend using [test kitchen](http://kitchen.ci/) to tie all this together on a local developer environment.

Assuming (on the other hand) you are in a good position to adopt a new technology like Docker, then, I then ask myself some very similar questions:

1. Where do I intend to run my docker application in production?
2. What orchestration technology will be used to deploy and manage the Docker container?
3. How will I build and store Docker images of each application release?

Jumping to an answer I would recommend the biggest and badest container management solution right now: [Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/). It is increasingly being provided as a native service by clouds like Google and Azure. Historically Kubernetes was hard to run it locally but that is now changing with the advent of tools like  [minikube](https://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/minikube/) or [minishift](https://www.openshift.org/minishift/). I will stop there.

In conclusion I hope my long rant was of some small benefit in your decision making.